# Why do I get: double free or corruption (top) after running this c++ script?

Tags: c++, debugging

I've got the following piece of code:

```
Class Chain
```

with

```
char* c;
```

as its only public atrib

```
istream& operator>>(istream& i, Chain& s) {
  delete [] s.c;
  const int L = 256;
  char *t = new char[L];
  i.getline(t,L);
  s.c = t;
  return i;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, Chain s) {
  o << s.c;
  return o;
}

#include <iostream>
#include "Chain.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

      Chain id;

      cin >> id;

      cout << id;
      cout << id;
```

After running the code under the Eclipse IDE on Xubuntu (last version) I get the following error:

> Error in [...] double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000008fd290 ***

What could be wrong?

Comment: Post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Every answer of this question will include guesswork about the internals of `Chain`, and that is bad.

Comment: My advice is to always set c to `nullptr` (or `NULL` or `0`) after you delete it. That way it will never be double-deleted.

Comment: @GrahamS That would most likely not help here as OP probably screwed up the copy constructor.

Comment: If this question was in an answerable state, it should most likely be dupe-hammered for stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: Yep fair point @BaummitAugen

Comment: Whyyyyyyy raw dynamic allocation for this?! And why three upvotes?!

Comment: @user3166611 To save you some time: Use a std::string instead of a char*. Raw owning pointers like that do not manage their own memory the way standard classes like std::string and std::vector do. It's very easy to accidentally double delete things (as you've done) when raw pointers are involved, and almost impossible when they aren't. You should not try to write classes with raw arrays or raw owning pointers until you fully understand things like the rule of three.

Comment: Abel: Those two lines are not code.

Comment: @Abel: Please, please, please do not format non-code as code, otherwise it is totally unreadable....

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, lol, how do you mean? Oh crap, I see :/ (still unreadable though, improved now)

Answer (score 5):

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, Chain s) {
```

That's not a reference on `s`, it's building an entire copy which probably has a destructor that deletes the memory used. And since you call this twice, it gets deleted twice.

Comment: Probably true. Still, answering questions where answering requires guesswork gives the wrong impression to the OP. Please try to avoid answering questions until they're properly formed!

Comment: I think psychic remote debugging is super sweet and awesome!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, this is C++, not a magic 8 ball. Given the code and the results shown, I'm pretty sure of my answer, and that's good enough to at least start a debugging session.

Comment: @Blindy: Well, exactly: Stack Overflow questions are not debugging sessions.

Answer (score 2):

Your class `Chain` most likely has a destructor that is destroying `c`. So at this line:

```
delete [] s.c;
```

You are deleting `c`, then when `Chain` gets deleted, it tries destroying `c` again to find it has already been deleted and you are doing a double free.

Comment: Yes I have that destructor, should I delete it?

Comment: No, even if you deleted the destructor, C++ creates one for you by default. Better to have one you define so you know what/how things are deleted.

Comment: @user3166611: All that would do is cause memory leaks. Programming by guessing doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. He's deleting the **previous** contents of `s.c` because he's about to reassign it. When the destructor runs, it only deletes the last one, the other deletions shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Barmar: I don't see what _else_ it could be other than a violation of the rule of zero/three/five. The key is the accidental copy. But then, we don't have all the information.